# Avg used on count

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a two tables that have following attributes

```
DOCTORS                  OPERATIONS
D_ID                       DATE
Name                       TYPE
Specialiation              DOCTORS_D_ID
                           PACIENTS_PACIENT_ID
```

I want to return name and ID of doctores that operated more than the average number of operations per doctor.

I have created following SQL command

```
  SELECT Name D_ID,COUNT(*) FROM DOCTORS 
    JOIN OPERATION 
      ON D_ID = DOCTORS_D_ID
      GROUP BY D_ID,Name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > ( SELECT AVG(COUNT(DOCTORs_D_ID))
                          FROM OPERATIONS GROUP by DOCTORS_D_ID )
```

this result in following table

```
D_ID        COUNTS(*)
Dr. Martin        3
```

In column D_ID is name instead of ID = only one of two attributes is returned in table. How can I return both - `name` and `D_ID` from this command?

Comment: Add a comma, i.e. do `SELECT Name, D_ID,...` As it is now you return the name, but renames the result column as d_id.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of nested aggregation functions.  I would just do this by calculating the average directly:

```
SELECT Name, D_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM DOCTORS JOIN
     OPERATION 
     ON D_ID = DOCTORS_D_ID
GROUP BY D_ID, Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT DOCTORs_D_ID))
                   FROM OPERATIONS
                  );
```

Comment: If the doctors always do at least one operation then this works but if there are doctors who do zero operations then the average returned by just using values from the operations table will be higher than the actual average as not all doctors are going to be represented.

Comment: @MT0 . . . Doctors who do no operations would not be in `OPERATIONS`.  Hence, they would not be in the OP's formulation either.  You may have a good point, but it should be made to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue of not counting doctors who do no operations in the average (in which case the average from just using the operations table [or an inner join with the operations table] will be higher than the actual answer from taking the number of operations in the operations table and the number of doctors in the doctors table).

To compensate for this you can do:

```
SELECT Name,
       D_ID,
       num_operations
FROM   ( SELECT Name,
                D_ID,
                COUNT( 1 ) OVER () AS num_doctors
         FROM   doctors ) d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT DISTINCT
                DOCTORS_D_ID,
                COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY DOCTORS_D_ID ) AS num_operations,
                COUNT( 1 ) OVER () AS total_operations
         FROM   operations ) o
       ON ( d.d_id = o.doctors_d_id )
WHERE  num_operations > total_operations / num_doctors;
```

It has the added bonus using analytic functions to calculate the counts rather than performing a third table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
with num_operations as
select doctors_d_id,count( * ) as operations from operations
group by   doctors_d_id and having count(*)>
(select avg(count(doctors_d_id) from operations group by doctors_d_id )
select doctors_d_id,operations,name from  num_operation a, doctors b 
where a.doctors_d_id=b.d_id
```